# Dump multiple geometry columns of a GeoDataFrame to Features in a FeatureCollection (GeoJSON) instead of properties?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I have a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) with some of its attributes that are geometries (only the `position` is the one which was interpreted as the *active* geometry when loading the data from [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/)):

```
import psycopg2
import geopandas as gpd
import json
# define a conn object for database retrieval
sql = 'SELECT id, position, buffer1, buffer2, buffer3 FROM table WHERE id = 11;'
gdf = gpd.read_postgis(sql, conn, geom_col='position')
```

Which leads to this resulting `gdf`:

[image: Resulting gdf]

I dump it as follow before returning this object (it's a function return value):

```
return json.loads(gdf.to_json())
```

It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [8.54, 47.36, 490.6]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "buffer1": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [ [8.5, 47.3],
              (...)
              [ 8.4, 47.4]
            ]
          ]
        },
        "buffer2": {
          "type": "MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [ [
                [8.5, 47.4],
                (...)
                [ 8.5, 47.6]
            ] ]
          ]
        },
        "buffer3": {
          "type": "MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [ [
                [8.2, 47.2],
                (...)
                [8.3, 47.7]
            ] ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Several points drew my attention from here:

- First; the CRS is not dumped. I don't know why?! It is definitely in the GeoDataFrame because when I ask for `gdf.CRS` it prints all the details of a `pyproj.crs.crs.CRS` object.
- Second point; all the other geometries are stored in the `'properties'` entry.
  It apparently "decided" to build a `FeatureCollection` (out of one record from the database, which is strange, but I'll live with it...). I would have preferred to have these extra 'bufferX' geometries as actual `Features` inside that `FeatureCollection` instead of just as `properties`. In such a structure for example; https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html?q=geojson. So it's a mess to bring them back to standard single GeoJSON object (it's possible but not clean).
- Last point; the `FeatureCollection` got the id `0`, and my id (`11`) is also stored in the `properties`. My wanted output would be like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [8.54, 47.36, 490.6]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "position"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [ [8.5, 47.3],
            [ 8.4, 47.4]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "buffer1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [ [
              [8.5, 47.4],
              [ 8.5, 47.6]
          ] ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "buffer2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [ [
              [8.2, 47.2],
              [8.3, 47.7]
          ] ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "buffer3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is: from an initial [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) which has several geometry columns, is there a simple way to construct a valid [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) object which has a single `FeatureCollection` containing each of these geometries as child `Features` (with a `name` attribute corresponding to its original column name and an `id` corresponding to the id used to get the data from the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database) and ***not*** as currently `properties` of a `FeatureCollection` containing only the *active* geometry column as a `Feature` and all other geometries as simple 'properties'?

There isn't much options yet to the [`.to_json()`](https://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=to_json#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json) method. :(

Useful link: https://jsonformatter.org/

Answer (score 0):

I end up with this "complicated" function to prepare a GeoJSON with a FeatureCollection containing multiple Features out of a GeoDataFrame with multiple geometry columns:

```
def gdf2geojson(gdf):
    import geojson
    from shapely.geometry import mapping
    columns = list(gdf.columns)
    features = []
    for col in columns:
        if col != 'id':
             # active geometry is a Shapely geometry instance and
             # has to be processed separately
            if col == gdf.geometry.name:
                geom = geojson.loads(
                    json.dumps(
                        mapping(
                            gdf.iloc[0][gdf.geometry.name]
                        )
                    )
                )
            else:
                geom = geojson.loads(gdf.iloc[0][col])
            
            properties = {
                "id": int(gdf.iloc[0]['id']),
                "name": col
            }
            feature = geojson.Feature(geometry=geom, properties=properties)
            features.append(feature)
    
    featCollection = geojson.FeatureCollection(features)

    return geojson.dumps(featCollection)
```

It works, but I hope I just missed a method somewhere that would have made my life a little easier.

Disclaimer; and it works because the gdf has only geometry columns (!), otherwise it becomes mandatory to implement a test somewhere to redirect non-geometry attributes into the property field of the GeoJSON object instead of the geometry field.

Comment: GeoJSON feature can have only one geometry https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#page-6. Definitions of GeoJSON Text and GeoJSON Objects sets that limitation.

Comment: Thx. But I've got FeatureCollection, or, as its name suggests, it's a collection of Features, like the geojsonObject presented [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html).

Comment: Yes, GeoJSON object can be a collection of features. Each of those features can have only one geometry. In your case you can present your data either with one geometry that is of geometry type GeometryCollection. Or like in the original example with one geometry and addional geometries as properties. If you want a feature with many geometries you must use some other format, like GML.

Comment: The previous comment gives the two possible ways to present the original feature that has many geometries as one GeoJSON feature. Your way to split data into several features is OK as well.